# Observer not save updated images gallery alt tag

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

i create simple module, which auto product name in images gallery alt tag

Evern :

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

        <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
            <observer name="imagesalttags_catalog_product_save_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CatalogProductSaveAfter" />
        </event>

    </config>
```

call observer :

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class CatalogProductSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $scopeConfigObject;

    protected $_storeManager;

    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $catalogProductHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfigObject,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->catalogProductHelper = $catalogProductHelper;
        $this->scopeConfigObject = $scopeConfigObject;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;


    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {   

        $product = $observer->getProduct();

        $pname = $product->getName();

        $existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();

        foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {

                    $entry->setLabel($pname);


                }
                $product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
                $product->save();   


        return ;
    }
}
```

But product save is not working, continue loader is display.
Please can you help it any one know how to save product data via observer for above case